# How to check if checkbox has been checked when hovering over an submit / anchor and display an alert prompting users to do so

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a little lost in working on this and need some help please.  I have a checkbox for terms and conditions that needs to be pressed before users can be registered. I have written some pseudo code in how I think it should be programmed.

```
//If user hovers over anchor
//Check to see if check box is checked
//If not checked
//Display alert saying "You need to check the terms and conditions"
//Else if - do not allow user to use anchor
//Else if user does check the box allow anchors to be used submitted
```

Hope that make sense.  Here is some of the code I have written but I am getting nowhere! Please help :)

```
    $("#checkbox1").click(function() {
          $("#id-reg-submit").attr("disabled", !this.checked);
        });
```

This above code is what I am using at the moment for users to actually click the box and prevents the moving forward in the sign up process.

What I need to do is get this to interacted with the other links (social media signup)
and the submit button, thus this is what I have so far:

```
 $(".wp-social-login-provider").hover(function(){
                            alert("Click The Terms & Conditions!");
                        });

                        if($("#checkbox1").click(function() {
                          $("#id-reg-submit").attr("disabled", !this.checked);
                        });){
                            $(".wp-social-login-provider").hover(function(){
                            alert("Click The Terms & Conditions!");
                        });
                        }else{
                            alert("hi");
                        }
```

I have been playing with code hover on and off stated trying to figure this out and have wrapped some code in an if else statement.

```
    if({$("#checkbox1").click(function() {
          $("#id-reg-submit").attr("disabled", !this.checked);
        }); &&  $( "a.wp-social-login-provider" ).hover(
          function() {
            $( this ).append( $( "<span> ***</span>" ) );
          }, function() {
            $( this ).find( "span:last" ).remove();
          }
        ); )} else{
            alert.("huhuuhu");
    }
```

As you can tell I need a little help! Can anyone help me please?

Cheers,

Max.

Comment: Why dont you disable you submit button, And make it enable only if checkbox is checked

Comment: That sounds good but I need to have an alert pop up too asking users to click the check box. Thanks!

Comment: So basically, you want some alert when user hover over any submit link or button when check box is not checked.

Comment: Hey Max, yes that is correct and thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Please mark answer if you think it is correct.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possible ways of getting this done, but since you have already provided a fiddle, I will follow your logic from there :)

Your logic in the fiddle you have provided is actually sound (sans a few typos), and I have expanded on it based on your requirements. Basically what you want to do is to disable the anchor link when it is hovered on, but only when the terms and conditions are not accepted/checked. Therefore, you can use a namespaced event (in case if you have other click events bound to it), which prevents the default link action from executing using `e.preventDefault()`. You turn this off if the `if` condition evaluates otherwise:

```
$('input[type=button], .something').on('mouseenter', function () {
    if(!$('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked')) {
        alert('Please accept the terms and conditions');
        $('.something').on('click.disable', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    } else {
        $('.something').off('click.disable');
    }
});
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/znrrsxyr/1/

The only flaw of this system is that if a user tabs his way to the anchor link, he/she can actually use the link because the if conditionals are only evaluated on mouseenter.

---

An alternative approach is instead of listening to events on the targets (button and anchor), you can listen to the `onChange` events of your checkbox, and decide if you want to enable the targets accordingly:

```
// Function: disable interactions
var disableActions = function() {
    $('.something').on('click.disable', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('input[type="button"]').prop('disabled');
    $('input[type="button"], .something').on('mouseenter.disable', function() {
        alert("Please check the terms and conditions.");
    });
}

// Disable interactions at runtime
disableActions();

// Conditional onchange
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    if(!$(this).prop('checked')) {
        disableActions();
    } else {
        $('input[type="button"]').prop('disabled', false);
        $('.something').off('click.disable');
        $('input[type="button"], .something').off('mouseenter.disable');
    }
});
```

See alternative solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/znrrsxyr/4/

Comment: Hi Terry, thanks so much for your answer! Not only did the code work but you have explained how it has worked and how my thoughts of programming this were a little off!  Could you recommend any books to help me get better at query / javascript? Cheers!!

Comment: @MaxJacobs There is no correct way to approach your issue :) multiple ways are possible, it's just that some people think differently and if it was me, I instinctively go for the second solution I have proposed only because I have been hardwired to think from the "triggering event" point of view. My jQuery knowledge is mostly self-taught, learning most of it on SO and the [official API docs](http://api.jquery.com).

Comment: Thank you again for your answer and help will check out the docs!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want to achieve? 
you can use event.preventDefault(); to stop the form from submitting.

```
$('input[type=button]').on('mouseenter', function() {
if($('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked')) { alert('true');} else {alert('false');}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c1d7j70u/

Comment: Hey Wlin, thanks for that.  Yes that is a step in the right direction but I also need to include the hover over the anchors too. Thanks for your help!

Comment: what do you mean by anchors? you want to prevent the social media submit from submit()?

Comment: @terry did an excellent job explaining, please accept his answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Here is an efficient solution as per Jquery standard.
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dx0s3pn9/5/)

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkBox"/>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Hello World">
    <a href="#" id="linkTo">MY link</a>






 $("#btn, #linkTo").on("mouseenter",function(){
   // $("#chkBox").is(":checked") ? alert("checked"): alert("not checked");   
});

$("#btn, #linkTo").on("click",function(e){
    $("#chkBox").is(":checked") ? alert("call your function and replace the alert"): e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Hey Max, that is pretty awesome too but I noticed that the alert box comes up twice? How could I prevent that from happening. Also I have comments out the alert for checked - http://jsfiddle.net/maxjacobs/q71c52cv/  How can I prevent it from popping up twice! Thanks to you and everyone helping :)

Comment: Hi Max, that is pretty sweet but I do not want the alert when checked!

Comment: What do you want instead of alert?

Comment: Nothing! Just the ability to click the links as long as the t&c's checkbox has been checked. Thank you :)

Comment: Let me know if you have if you update your JSFiddle and I will mark as the answer, thanks to all who helped :)

Comment: Check the updated link. Now when you dont check the checkbox the link and button wont work.